# Build taxonomy categories with views, only children

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to build a menu with taxonomy terms and views.

Lets say that I have a tree of taxonomy terms

1. Parent-1

   - child-1.1

     - grandchild-1.1.1

       - greatgrandchild-1.1.1.1
       - greatgrandchild-1.1.1.2
     - grandchild 1.1.2
   - child-1.2

     - grandchild 1.2.1

       - greatgrandchild-1.2.1.1
       - greatgrandchild-1.2.1.2
     - grandchild 1.2.2

I am having problems viewing only the children of the taxonomy menu. I want to exclude the current level, and only see the children, not the grandchildren of an item. So for instance.

When I am viewing child-1.1, I only want to see grandchild-1.1.1 and grandchild-1.1.2, not any of the great grand children. I don't want to see child-1.2 or the parents.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set up your Taxonomy view to accept the argument *Parent term* and pass it the current term? I don't know how complex your view is, but I got it to work in this basic example:

**View type:** Term
**Add arguments:** Taxonomy: Parent term
**Action to take if argument is not present:** Hide view / Page not found (404)
**Validator:** Taxonomy term
**Argument type:** Term ID
**Add fields:** Taxonomy: Term Term

That will display only the current term's children, i.e. those that have the current term as a parent.

Comment: Hi Jan, I was wondering if you could tell me were View Type, Add Arguments, and add field was? I thought you referred you contextual filter Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) but I could not find them. Thank you