# Can I make a Drupal Book page parent with no content?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to Organize Drupal Book pages under parent pages that are just headings, are not links and have no content?

I want to separate pages under headings but I don't want to create pages for these headings, just to add text to the navigation and use as a parent for pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a new content type, call it headings, remove the body from it and let it have children.

see http://yoursite.com/#overlay=admin/structure/types/add

Create the heading content type and remove the body, add or remove anything you want or don't want while your there.

Then see:
http://yoursite.com/#overlay=admin/content/book/settings

Add the new content type to the books modules allowed content types and your done.

Comment: is it possible to remove the link to the heading content type in the book navigation block? I've removed the body but it still links to the heading content.

Comment: Without creating a module from scratch without back linking you could just create a taxonomy type called header, assign that to the book you want it with and create a custom view to display the book.

Comment: Also you could do a view for it and not let it link the heading content type I think, I've never tried that though.  It would also be an exhaustive write up. You'll need views for that either way though. And with those criteria I'd say taxonomy is your simplest fastest bet.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8011/build-taxonomy-categories-with-views-only-children might help

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly an easy solution but those are the options.

Answer (score 0):

For the Book module, each book is associated with a top-level page, which is a node; you cannot have a book without that node.

If you don't want content, you can simply leave the body of the top-level page empty.
As for not having a link shown in the navigation tree, that is only possible if you create a custom module that alters the content of the block output from [book_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_block_view/7).